# Cannot fix broken link to .lyrx file in ArcGIS pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, layer-file, data-source

When I drag and drop a .lyrx file into ArcGIS, the red exclamation mark indicating a broken data link appears. When I click on the red exclamation mark and try to fix the file link within ArcGIS, the .lyrx file does not appear in the folder in which it is located.

[image: When I click on the red exclamation mark and try to fix the file link within ArcGIS, the .lyrx file does not appear in the folder in which it is located.]

I have other .lyrx files and when I drag and drop these into ArcGIS pro, I have no issues.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what is happening and what I can do to open this file?

I have all the associated files with this .lyrx file in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to connect the layer to .lyrx file, you need to connect it to its data source.  The .lyrx file defines a layer (or set of layers) and each layer includes a reference to a data source (eg, a shapefile, or a feature class within a database).  You need to point the layer to its data source.

You can see where it is looking for its data source by double-clicking the layer (or by right-click the layer, then select 'Properties') to open the Properties window.  In the Properties window, select the "Source" section.  Take a look at the information there to see what the layer's data source was saved as (when the .lyrx was created).  This might give you some idea of where to look for the correct data source.

You can then correct the data source by clicking the Source button at the top-right of this window, OR by closing the window and clicking the red excamation mark.  Then you need to select a suitable feature class for the data source (must be the correct geometry - point, line, polygon - that the layer expects).

If you choose the exclamation mark method, ArcGIS Pro will attempt to also fix any other broken layers that used the same original database/workspace as the one your are fixing.